# jython properly arrange data into columns

Tags: websphere, jython

I am having data but it is not properly formatted. How can I properly arrange it into proper columns using Jython?

Ex:

`Active Threads/Pool Size/Max Pool       WEB:            ORB:       Activetran      CPU

ABC                     1:20:100            0:1:50              0                      1

EFG                     1:19:100            0:2:50              0                      1

MSG                     0:0:50            0:0:50              0                      0

ABAAASAA                     1:2:50            0:10:50              0                      0

BBASADDADADDAB                     0:0:50            0:0:50              0                      0

BVA                     1:20:100            0:1:50              0                      1`

Answer (score 0):

```py
n1 = 1
n2 = 2
s = 'a'

print '%4d : %4d : %4s' % (n1, n2, s)
```

For more details see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting